# receiving time stamp in another timezone

Tags: php, datetime

may be you know why this doesnt work (trying to receive timeStamp in another timeZone):

```
$from_zone = 'Europe/Kiev';
$to_zone = 'US/Eastern';
$stamp = 1383897599;

$from_tz = new DateTimeZone($from_zone);
$to_tz = new DateTimeZone($to_zone);

$dateTime = new DateTime(null, $from_tz);
$dateTime->setTimestamp($stamp);

$dateTime->setTimeZone($to_tz);

$new_stamp = $dateTime->getTimestamp();
echo $new_stamp;
```

return initial timeStamp instead of the new one, what im doing wrong ? :\

Comment: You can use `$dt->getTimestamp() + $dt->getOffset()` to get timestamp with offset, but you must know what you are doing, and this is bad practice IMHO

Answer (score 1):

UNIX timestamps are by definition based on UTC. A timestamp will always return same date/time regardless of time zone.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time):

> Unix time, or POSIX time, is a system for describing instants in time, defined as the number of seconds elapsed **since midnight Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)** of Thursday, January 1, 1970

Comment: actually not ... timestamp somewhere in US where lets say now 2 PM and timestamp in Europe lets say some where 8PM will be different simply because start point the same is jan 1 1970 but end time point is different, so you are wrong

Comment: @Eugene: UTC is international. It is always the same at every part of the world. Since the end point is *also* UTC, it will be the same everywhere.

Comment: who said end point also UTC ? if timestamp be a constant it would be useless :)

Comment: @Eugene: Timezone data is *not* embedded in the timestamp. Timestamp stores just number of seconds since Unix epoch.

Comment: looks like we are talking about different things ... im not talking to you about the return of the time() im about timestamp in general

Comment: @Eugene: **timestamp in general is NOT timezone avare**. If you are not talking about timestamp, you should not use `timestamp` word. See [demo](https://eval.in/64568), where same date in presented in all timezones, and timestamp is always the same.

Answer (score -1):

Timestamp is a number of seconds passed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC. Changing timezones does not affect that value, as well as [time()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) function returns the same value independently of the set timezone.

If you need different timestamps, try using [strtotime($dateString)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), as it is affected by timezones, like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Kiev');
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $date . ' - ' . strtotime($date) . '<br />';
date_default_timezone_set('US/Eastern');
echo $date . ' - ' . strtotime($date) . '<br />';
```

which prints:

```
2013-11-08 20:48:47 - 1383936527
2013-11-08 20:48:47 - 1383961727
```

Comment: i thought possible without additional double conversion or without offset (btw i would prefer offset instead of double conversion)

Comment: IMO, this example is just misleading people into thinking they can get different timestamps for same date; but in your example, there are NOT the same date! There is 7hour difference between this 2 dates, and with a reason = **they are in different timezone**. `2013-11-09 11:26:30 UTC+2` is not same as `2013-11-09 11:26:30 UTC-5`, [see demo](https://eval.in/64546).